# 400 Bad Request in NodeJs Application

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, body-parser, passport-local

When ever I submit a from to login in or get registered I get 400 bad request. But in register route the user get registered but it also gives bad request. When we go to login route same as register route I get BAD REQUEST.   0

I am using the following dependencies:

`express session`
`passport`
`passport-local`
`passport-local-mongoose`

Is there something wrong with the implementation of the `passport-local-mongoose` or its `passport` side or `serialize` or `deserialize`  the user. Can anybody help me with this problem I am stuck on this for three days. Here is some code.

```js
//-----------------------//Require---------------------
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const session = require("express-session");
const passport = require("passport");
const LocalStrategy= require("passport-local").Strategy;
const passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
//-----------------------//App.use---------------------

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(session({
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));
//-----------------------//Passport---------------------
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

//-----------------------//Mongoose---------------------
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/Twitter', {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);
const tweetschema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    tweets: String
});
//-----------------------//Schema Plgin---------------------
tweetschema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);


//-----------------------//New Model---------------------

const Tweet = new mongoose.model("Tweet", tweetschema);

//-----------------------//Local Strategy-------------------
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(Tweet.authenticate()));

//-----------------------//Seralize Passport---------------------
passport.serializeUser(Tweet.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(Tweet.deserializeUser());
//-----------------------//Get Routes---------------------

app.get("/" ,(req, res)=>{
    Tweet.find({}, function(err, founItems){
        res.render("home", {founItems:founItems});
    });
});

app.get("/tweets", (req, res)=>{
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
    res.render("Tweets");

    }else{
        res.redirect("/login");
    }
});
//-----------------------//Post Routes---------------------

app.post("/login", (req, res)=>{
    
    
    const user = new Tweet({
        username: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password
    });
    
    req.logIn(user, (err)=>{
        if(err){
            res.send(err);
        }
        passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, ()=>{
            console.log("Successfull.");
        })
    })
});

app.post("/reg", (req, res)=>{
    Tweet.register({username: req.body.email}, req.body.password, (err, user)=>{
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect("/reg");
        }else{
            if(user){
                passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, ()=>{
                    res.redirect("/tweets");
                    console.log("Successfully Regsitered The User!");
                })
            }
        }
    })

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You redirect user to /login route, but you don't have get request for this.

If you have it but not uploaded try this in Seralize Passport

```
passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});
```

What about this:

```
app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  const email = req.body.email;
  User.findOne({ username: email }, function (err, u) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      if (u) {
        u.authenticate(req.body.password, (err, model, info) => {
          if (info) {
            res.send("Wrong email or password!");
          }
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
          } else if (model) {
            req.login(u, (err) => {
              if (err) {
                console.log(err);
              } else {
                passport.authenticate("local");
                req.session.save((error) => {
                  if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                  } else {
                    res.redirect("/");
                  }
                });
              }
            });
          }
        });
      } else {
        res.send("Wrong email or password!");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

So you first search user in the database with email: `User.findOne({ username: email }, function (err, u){}` I suggest to make username unique `username: { type: String, unique: true}` in `tweetSchema`.
After that you check for `err`. If `u` exists, you authenticate it with password. According to [passport-local-mongoose-](https://github.com/saintedlama/passport-local-mongoose#authenticatepassword-cb) `u.authenticate(password, (err, model, info)=>{})` has two arguments: password and callback function. In callback we check for `info` which is "an instance of AuthenticationError describing the reason the password failed, else undefined." After that we check for `err` and it is "null unless the hashing algorithm throws an error." And finally, we check for `model` that is "the model getting authenticated if authentication was successful otherwise false."

So, model is authenticated. After that we must use the user with `req.login(u,(err))`. Check for errors and if everything is alright, we authenticate user locally `passport.authenticate("local");`. If you want to save session, write:

```
req.session.save((error) => {
                      if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                      } else {
                        res.redirect("/");
                      }
                    });
```

That's all.

For registration :

```
app.post("/register", (req, res) => {
  const email = req.body.email;
  const password = req.body.password
  User.find({ email: email }, function (err, docs) {
    if (docs.length === 0) {
      User.register(
        {
          username: email,
        },
        password,
        function (err, user) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
          } else {
            req.login(user, (err) => {
              if (err) {
                console.log(err);
              } else {
                passport.authenticate("local");
                req.session.save((error) => {
                  if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                  } else {
                    res.redirect("/");
                  }
                });
              }
            });
          }
        }
      );
    } else {
      res.send("The accout already exists!");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Nope I already tried that but it didn't work. If you have any other solution please tell me.

Comment: Try this updated answer. If it works, I'll write for registration too.

Comment: Brother I can't thank you enough. It worked and can you explain me the part `u.authenticate` from my knowledge I think  we can only use `passport.authenticate` and do we always have to save the session `req.session.save`. If you have any documentation on it please let me know and one last thing where did this line and callback came from `u.authenticate(req.body.password, (err, model, info)`. If possibal can you also write registration route and explain it to me. Thanks once again.

Comment: You're welcome. I've updated the answer. Without session user will constantly have to write his password to login. You can add `cookie: { maxAge: value },` in `app.session` and so user won't have to login for specific time period.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session